# Tab Swipe View in landscape, plain layout in portrait

Tags: android, android-layout, view, orientation, swipe

My App is supposed to show a plain LinearLayout with a ListView and TextView when in portrait, but a SwipeView with three tabs when in landscape. The layout is to be changed whenever the orientation of the phone is changed.

I get that normally you'd just have two layout files for portrait and lanndscape but I feel that won't be sufficient in my case. After all the Tab and Swipe functionality requires more than just an XML file. While looking for solutions to my problem it was suggested starting a new activity in the onConfigurationChanged() method, but at the same time this was stated to be very bad practice leading to all sorts of problems.

Now I thought about adding a whole lot of if-else statements to my TagActivity.java always checking what the current orientation is and spawning whatever is needed. Would this be a good way to do it? Is it possible to have multiple onCreate() Methods, one for each orientation?

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

The tutorial I used to implement the TabActivity was the one from androidhive:
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in a recent project. We ended up using a view pager with PagerSlidingTabStrip (https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/issues/5). In portrait only show one fragment in the view pager and hide the tabs, and in landscape populate out the view pager and tabs. Not sure if this works in your particular situation (it seems like it would), but food for thought.

Comment: Thanks for the input! That seems like it should work.